# height:auto not displaying js image carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have read about resizing images using max-width:100% and height auto and it works great for me with a single image however if I use that on the images in a js carousel I need to put in dimensions for height otherwise the images don't show? Is it possible something within the js file? Here is my html & css.. Thanks for your help!

```
    <div id="slider">

        <ul class="slider">
           <li><img src="img/img4.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;" /></li>

           <li><img src="img/img5.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;"/></li>

       </ul>

    </div>



#slider {margin: 0 auto;


}

.slider {margin: 0 auto;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          width:100%;
          height:400px;


}

.slider li {display: none;
          position: absolute; 
          top: 0; 
          left: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li` elements inside the slider have an absolute positioning, so them and the elements inside are freely positioned. This roughly means that they don't 'fill' the slide element, which is sad and empty.

I guess you want a super quick answer with a jsfiddle on it, but if you have some time, read this:

http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101/

And for quick solutions, use a custom slider:

https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe

Comment: Sorry, this is the good link to learn: http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101

Comment: Thanks Hector, I'll read through the links, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't know exactly your problem beacause you didn't give the js. However if you want to make a responsive slide, this is one of the best plugin for you http://docs.dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/

Comment: Thanks Duc, I'll look over that now as well!